# Evitar el uso de if y hardcoded string

Tags: c++

Hay alguna manera de evitar el uso de if y los string harcoded en la función redirect, tal vez usando templates (meta programación).. La idea es recibir un string y llamar a una función.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void account()
{
    std::cout << "accout method" << std::endl;
}

void status()
{
    std::cout << "status method" << std::endl;
}

void redirect(std::string method_to_call)
{
    if(method_to_call == "account")
    {
        account();
    }
    else if(method_to_call == "status")
    {
        status();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "method not found!!" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string method_name;
    std::cin >> method_name;

    redirect(method_name);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El truco consiste en buscar, dentro de las cadenas que quieres comprobar, una característica **unica** que te permita distinguirlas entre ellas sin necesidad de compararlas 1 a 1.

En el ejemplo simple que expones, con solo 2 cadenas, tienes 4 métodos válidos:

1. Por el contenido de una determinada posición (en tu ejemplo, la letra inicial).
2. Por la longitud.
3. Buscando en una lista auxiliar.
4. Calculando una *firma* de la cadena.

Los 2 primeros son los más fáciles de implementar; desgraciadamente, requieren validad **previamente** la cadena; es decir, no comprueban **toda** la cadena, solo determinadas propiedades. El método 1 confundiría entre `"hola"` e `"hijo"` (ambas empiezan con `'h'`). El método 2 cometería el mismo herror: ambas son de 4 caracteres.

El 3 realiza la comprobación por si mismo. En realidad, se trata de un *encadenamiento* de comprobación literal. Compruebas las cadenas 1 a 1, de forma automática. Y es propenso a errores.

El 4 es mucho mas genérico, y da pie a *automatizar* el proceso, mediante estructuras adicionales, tales como `std:map`. Y evita errores, al poder *adjuntar* información adicional a las cadenas.

Te expongo un ejemplo de cada método; puede que tengan algún *errorcillo* (no los he comprobado), pero ilustran los distintos métodos expuestos:

#### Por el contendido de una determinada posición.

```
void redirect( const std::string &method_to_call ) {
  switch( method_to_call[0] ) {
  case 'a':
    account( );
    break;

  case 's':
    status( );
    break;

  default:
    std::cout << "method not found!!" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

#### Por la longitud.

```
void redirect( const std::string &method_to_call ) {
  switch( method_to_call.size( ) ) {
  case 7:
    account( );
    break;

  case 6:
    status( );
    break;

  default:
    std::cout << "method not found!!" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

#### Buscando en una lista.

```
::std::list< ::std::string > KeywordsList;
KeywordsList.push_front( "accout" );
KeywordsList.push_front( "status" );

...

void redirect( const std::string &method_to_call ) {
  auto iter = find( KeywordsList.begin( ),
                    KeywordsList.end( ),
                    method_to_call );

  switch( distance( iter, KeywordsList.end( ) ) {
  case 0:
    status( );
    break;

  case 1:
    account( );
    break;

  default:
    std::cout << "method not found!!" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

#### Calculando una *firma* de la cadena.

```
std::size_t myhash( const ::std::string &s ) {
  static ::std::hash< ::std::string > h{ };

  return h( s );
}

...

const KStatus = myhash( "status" );
const KAccount = myhash( "account" );

...

void redirect( const std::string &method_to_call ) {
  switch( myhash( method_to_call ) {
  case KStatus:
    status( );
    break;

  case KAccount:
    account( );
    break;

  default:
    std::cout << "method not found!!" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

#### Bonus: `::std::unordered_map< >`.

Este es el método **mas potente** de todos. Y uno de los mas rápidos.

```
void account( ) {
  ...
}

void status( ) {
  ...
}

::std::unordered_map< ::std::string, ::std::function< void( ) > > Keywords{
  { "account", account },
  { "status", status }
}

...

void redirect( const std::string &method_to_call ) {
  auto iter = Keywords.find( method_to_call );

  if( iter == Keywords.end( ) ) {
    std::cout << "method not found!!" << std::endl;
  } else {
    iter->second( );
  }
}
```

Comment: el método bonus me gusta, lo usaré en el proyecto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @jsubi Un placer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo un método mas complejo, asociar *string* a *enum*. Hay un montón de métodos, artículos y código que lo hace. Te explico mas o menos como sería el asunto:
Declaras tu tipo *enum* y un *define* asociado:

```
enum e_redirect {e_account = 0, e_status = 1};
#define _e_redirect _T(",account=0,status=1,")
```

Y unas rutinas de intercambio de datos:

```
inline e_redirect eredirect (const CString &v)
{  return ((e_redirect) iCvEnum(v,_e_redirect));}
```

Así tu programa quedaría como:

```
void redirect(e_redirect ee)
{
   switch (ee)
   {
      case e_account: account(); break;
      case e_status:  status();  break;

      default: 
         std::cout << "method not found!!" << std::endl; 
         break;
   }
}

int main()
{
    std::string method_name;
    std::cin >> method_name;

    CString cs(method_name.c_str());

    redirect(eredirect(cs));
}
```

No nos engañemos, sigue siendo hardcoded pero es un truco que te permite utilizar *switch* en vez de los *if* encadenados que ensucian, a mi juicio, mucho el código, además estas rutinas te permiten hacer el proceso inverso, es decir, puedes obtener el valor string de *e_redirect* pero para eso se necesitan otras rutinas que si te interesa, me dices y te los paso.

Para utilizar **iCVEnum (v,_e_redirect)** necesitarás estas rutinas:

```
bool bDameIzOde (CString &extremo, const CString &completo, const CString &sep=_sepSV, 
                 bool izdo=true, bool por_iz=true)
{
   int           pos;


   // Posición del separador. ¿Se busca, por la izquierda o por la derecha?
   pos = (por_iz? completo.Find (sep) : completo.ReverseFind (sep[0]));
   if (pos == -1) return (false); // No ha encontrado ningún separador.

   if (izdo) // ¿Extremo izquierdo o el derecho?
        extremo = completo.Left (pos);
   else extremo = completo.Right (completo.GetLength() - (pos + sep.GetLength()));

   return (true);
}

inline int iInt (const CString &valor, int base = 0)
{  // "nullptr" por que no quiero recuperar el resto de la cadena no convertida, 
   // "0" indica a "_tcstoul" que la base numérica se deduce de los primeros caracteres de la cadena
   return (_tcstoul(valor, nullptr, base));
}

inline int iCvEnum (CString v, const CString &def)
{  // Valor comprendido entre ",valor string=" y el separador (,). "iInt" filtra el separador final
   return (bDameIzOde (v, def, _enu_sep + v + _enu_STRsepVAL, false) ? iInt(v) : _enu_ERR);
}
```

Sí, utilizo **CString** pero supongo no será difícil utilizar el homólogo en *string*

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, un método muy interesante.

Answer (score 0):

Si todas las funciones van a ser tan sencillas, usa un mapa de punteros a función:

```
using funciones_t = std::map<std::string, void(*)()>;

funciones_t funciones
{
    {"account", account},
    {"status", status},
};
```

Con ese mapa de punteros a función, puedes cambiar tu método `redirect` de la siguiente manera:

```
void redirect(std::string method_to_call)
{
    auto found = funciones.find(method_to_call);
    if (found != funciones.end())
    {
        (found->second)();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "method not found!!\n";
    }
}
```

Como ves se evita el abuso de `if` y no hay ni una sola cadena *hardcode*ada.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en  <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hRDniOGljPKsLAcr)</kbd>.

Comment: buen sistema y queda el código muy limpio, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he optado por una mezcla de varias soluciones que he visto en stackoverflow, implemento las funciones que quiero ejecutar en classes derivadas de action y pongo el código dentro del operador() y incluyo un puntero de la classe derivada en un mapa donde tengo el nombre de la classe y un puntero a ella.. es un poco rebuscado pero evito totalmente hardcodear string's..

```
// STL
#include <typeinfo>

class action
{
public:
        static void add(action* act);
        static action* const get_action(const std::string& name);
        virtual const tx operator()(const std::vector<std::string>& params) = 0;

private:
        static std::map<std::string, action*> action_list;
};

std::map<std::string, action*> action::action_list;

// register new action
void action::add(action* act)
{
        if(act == nullptr)
                return;

        action_list[typeid(*act).name()] = act;
}

action* const action::get_action(const std::string& name)
{
        for(auto it = action_list.cbegin(); it != action_list.cend(); it++)
        {
                if(it->first.find(name) != std::string::npos)
                        return it->second;
        }

        return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Sólo veo un inconveniente, consumo de memoria, y además *static*